# iPod 4th gen screen does not work after replacement

Tags: ipod-touch

I cracked the screen of my iPod 4th gen, and bought a replacement kit to replace it. I replaced it, and before applying adhesive, I checked to see it work. It worked fine, it was responsive, etc. But I couldn't close the case because the digitizer extended to the top part of the screen, and needed to be put into place. While doing that, the screen attachment came off -- while the screen was still on, and it went pitch black. Now it does not respond to anything. It's not recognized by the computer and iTunes either. What could have happened? Could it be fixed after this point?

Edit: connecting to power does not turn it on either.

Comment: Is this an iPod or an iPod Touch? The tags say both ...

Comment: iPod touch. I'll fix it right now, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical term you are looking for is "it's busted"

If I read the sequence correctly, you disconnected a major component while the device was operating and now it is unresponsive. Some electronic components can be disconnected without damage, others don't like it and express their displeasure by declining to work again.

Bare minimum, you will need another, known-working screen to see if the screen or the main board is damaged. The cracked screen is fine, IF it was actually working before replacement (cracked glass is fine, cracked glass + no display is not fine). Repair centers keep various components handy for exactly this reason.

if the known-good screen doesn't work, then you have fried the logic board. At $250 for a new iPod we have to seriously consider how much more effort we want to put into more repairs.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I can always get it replaced for $99 anyways. Given that I also severed the volume/power ribbon, I won't bother with it. I just wanted to try it on my own for fun, and now I know what not to do in the future. Thank you for your help.